# How to set position of Radio Group

Tags: android, android-layout

I am creating a `RadioGroup` dynamically from an `ArrayList` that I have stored in an object but when I add it to the view, it appears on top of the `TextView` that I have above it.  What can I do to stop this from happening?

I am also setting the `TextView` based on another field in the object.

Thanks to anyone looking at this!

```
            text.setText(list.get(counter).getText().toString());
            image.setImageBitmap(result);
            a = list.get(counter).getA();

            for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++){

                RadioButton btn = new RadioButton(MainActivity.this);
                btn.setId(i);
                btn.setText(a.get(i));
                btn.setChecked(false);

                radioGroup.addView(btn);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

OK. I figured it out.  i was able to accomplish this by setting some `LayoutParams` and then by using `addRule()`

```
 layout = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layout.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, text.getId());
    radiogroup.setLayoutParams(layout);
```